# How to detect the last string of a TextView contains 0 to 9

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner in Android software development. I'm making a calculator app to test my skills. In a calculator there are 0-9 numeric and some others operators like +, -, *, / etc.
In the time of Equal functionality, I have to make sure that the last string of the TextView has any number (0-9), not any operators.

My equal fun is like that:

```
fun onEqual(view: View) {
    if (tv_input.text.contains("0-9")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Last string is a number, not operator", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: use Regex for this type of condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Kotlin regular expression [matches](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/matches.html#matches)

```
val lastString = "573" // input
val pattern = "-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?".toRegex()
/**
-?         allows zero or more - for negative numbers in the string.
\\d+       checks the string must have at least 1 or more numbers (\\d).
(\\.\\d+)? allows zero or more of the given pattern (\\.\\d+) 
           In which \\. checks if the string contains . (decimal points) or not
           If yes, it should be followed by at least one or more number \\d+.
**/
val isLastString = pattern.matches(lastString)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/ends-with.html

```
fun String.endsWith(
    suffix: String,
    ignoreCase: Boolean = false
): Boolean
```

Returns true if this string ends with the specified suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.
I did my own solution.

Here is the code I've wrote:

```
fun onEqual(view: View) {
    if (!tv_input.text.toString().equals("")) {
        val last = tv_input.text.toString()
        val lastNumber: String = last.get(last.length - 1).toString()
        Toast.makeText(this, lastNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the last character, you can just do ``tv_input.text.toString().last()`` - no need to mess around with indices. (Or ``lastOrNull()`` to be safe, e.g. if the text field is empty)

Comment: You're genius boss. saved my lots of times.